# Information about In-functions Variables Besides locals() Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, local-variables

This code, as expected, raises an UnboundLocalError.

```
x = 3

def f():
    print("locals: " + str(locals()))
    if x==3:
        print("x is 3!")
    x = 1

f()
```

However, as we can see from the output, locals() is an empty dictionary at the beginning:

```
locals: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/try/scatch.py", line 10, in <module>
    f()
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/try/scatch.py", line 6, in f
    if x==3:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

From what I gathered, locals dictionary holds all of the information about the in-functions variables that Python knows. Clearly, this is not the case: there must be some information about the variables inside of the function besides locals().

My question is - what is this information exactly? Can we access at the beginning of the function to the list of the variables inside it?

Comment: _Clearly, this is not the case_ Why do you say that?  At the point in the function where you call `locals()`, there are no local variables.  `x = 1` does not occur until later in the function...

Comment: `locals()` would give you give you local variables that have been bound (assigned to) at the point you access them. Variables considered local in given context as per scope rules are not the same thing. However, I do not recall their being an iface to access list of those from any point within a given block.

Comment: @JohnGordon - Python 'knows' that x variable will be redefined later. Since this info isn't included over locals(), there must be another place which holds it.

Comment: @OndrejK. - that's what I meant :) perhaps I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you're looking for in CPython is `f.__code__.co_varnames` documented in the [**`inspect`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

```
>>> def f():
...     print(f.__code__.co_varnames)
...     x = 1
...     y = 2
>>> f()
('x', 'y')
```

Answer (score 2):

While `f.__code__.co_varnames` (as pointed out [in orlp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621541/4349415)) works, here's way to find local assignments with [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
import inspect,ast

x = 3

def find_ass_in_func(func):
    f_src = inspect.getsource(f)
    f_ast = ast.parse(f_src)
    return find_ass_in_src(f_ast.body)
def find_ass_in_src(bodies):
    ass = set()
    for b in bodies:
        if isinstance(b, ast.Assign):
            ass |= set(t.id for t in b.targets)
        if(hasattr(b, "body")):
            ass |= find_ass_in_src(b.body)
    return ass

def f():
    print("locals: " + str(locals()))
    print("local variables:", find_ass_in_func(f))
    if x==3:
        print("x is 3!")
        x = 5
        y = 6 # just for demonstration purpose
    x = 1

f()
```

Output:

```
locals: {}
local variables: {'x', 'y'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    f()
  File "test.py", line 21, in f
    if x==3:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```